# How can I use images in a tkinter grid?

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, grid

Here is the code I am working with. I just cannot see where to insert the images into the grid. I know `fill' is for`color`should I use`image.open`? If so where does that go in the grid?

```
class photo():  # take the photo
    def __init__(self,filename=None):
        with picamera.PiCamera() as cam:
            cam.resolution= (640, 480)
            cam.framerate = 60
            cam.AWB_MODES
            cam.EXPOSURE_MODES
            for effect in cam.IMAGE_EFFECTS:
                cam.image_effect=random
            for i in range(1000):
                cam.capture('/home/pi/Pictures/camFolder/img_%i.jpg')
                time.sleep(2)

class App(tk.Tk):  # build the grid
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=1000, height=1000, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack(side="top",fill="both", expand="true")
        self.rows= 10
        self.columns =10
        self.cellwidth =100
        self.cellheight =100
        self.rect = {}
        self.oval = {}
        for column in range(20):
            for row in range(20):
                x1 = column*self.cellwidth
                y1= row * self.cellwidth
                x2 = x1 + self.cellwidth
                y2 = y1 + self.cellheight
                self.rect[row,column]= self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2, fill ="blue", tags="rect")
                self.oval[row,column]= self.canvas.create_oval(x1+2,y1+2,x2-2,y2-2, fill="blue", tags="oval")

        self.redraw(1000)

    def redraw(self,delay):
        self.canvas.itemconfig("rect", fill="blue")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("oval", fill="yellow")
        for i in range(10):
            row = random.randint(0,19)
            col = random.randint(0,19)
            item_id = self.oval[row,col]
            self.canvas.itemconfig(item_id, fill="blue")
        self.after(delay, lambda: self.redraw(delay))

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I am new to Python and I have been learning on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use use tkinter's PhotoImage to add images to your program. Here's a short [doc](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) that shows you how.

You can use it like this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("lenna.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # this line need to prevent gc
label.pack()
```

Note: tkinter does not support jpg or png or many other types, you will need to use PIL or Pillow fork as seem above. The only supported formats are GIF and PGM/PPM in which you wouldn't need to use PIL.

Comment: Your effbot.org link is currently dead